# Problema al alinear elementos a la derecha que se superpongan (bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de alinear dos "botones" (links) a la derecha en bootstrap.

Mis objetivos son dos:

1. Que queden lo más alineados posibles a la derecha.
2. Que siempre haya un pequeño margen entre ellos.

Si bien al principio la separación entre ambos es más o menos la correcta y puedo conseguir que queden alineados a la derecha sin un margen excesivo del último elemento en el lado derecho, al ir reduciendo el tamaño de la página, ambos acaban superponiendose.

He conseguido hacer que esto no ocurra a base de ponerles clases mr-x, mr-sm-x,... pero veo que no tiene ningún sentido ya que para que funcione más o menos bien, he de poner una cantidad excesiva de clases. Algo así como:

```
ml-3 ml-sm-1 ml-md-1 mr-4 mr-sm-2 mr-md-2 mr-lg-1 mr-xl-0
```

Y el resultado tampoco es el óptimo.

He intentado hacerlo funcionar con las clases *offset*, con *align-items-end* y con *justify-content-end*. También con *float-right*, pero siempre tengo problemas con los margenes y la superposición.

A continuación dejo algunas imágenes que muestran el problema y el ejemplo en jsfiddle.

[image: Inicialmente se muestran así.]

[image: Al ir reduciendo el tamaño de pantalla acaba pasando esto]

[image: Lo ideal sería que se mostrasen siempre así]

[Ejemplo con el código en jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oms02/7w9pqekz/6/)

Answer (score 0):

La mayoria de los problemas de CSS tienen su raíz en HTML. En el ejemplo que pones tienes principalmente 2 errores:

**1.-Usar .col para cada botón**

Los .col deben ser usados para contener un conjunto de contenido, en este caso el conjunto son ambos botones.

**2.-Mal uso del .navbar**

Como no muestras el código completo no puedo entender tu contexto, pero asumo que lo que muestras no es el menú de navegación principal, por lo tanto no deberías usar la etiqueta .navbar

Una solución podría ser la siguiente

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="heading-title"> Título </h1>

  <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="botones pt-2">
      
        <a class="btn" href="#" role="button">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </a>

        <a class="btn" href="#" role="button">
          <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
        </a>
        
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.heading-title {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FF8601;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem; /* Aquí elije el tamaño */
}

.btn {
    background-color: #EEE;
    border:2px solid orange;
}
.botones {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probaste agregando una clase a los div de los botones y colocando un margin-right y margin-top ?,también podrías usar una de las clases de bootstrap algo tipo container en esos div, (coloque las medidas en px pero puedes colocarlas en rem u otra para que el tamaño varíe según el tamaño y sea fluido el responsive) :

por ejemplo:

```
.heading-title {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FF8601;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #EEE;
    border:2px solid orange;

}

.prueba{
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

<!--
```

### Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs

```
<div class="container">

  <nav class="navbar heading-title">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Título</span>
  </nav>

  <nav class="navbar row justify-content-end">
    <div class="prueba col-1">
      <a class="btn" href="#" role="button">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class=" prueba col-1">
      <a class="btn" href="#" role="button">
        <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
```